# Spring Data: How to write a record in join table for unidirectional one-to-may?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a `Subscription` class and `Payment` class. When I do the following, it doesn't create a record in join table. Should I use intermediate class or is it possible to create such record without it? `subscriptionRepository` is a `CrudRepository` from Spring-Data.

```
@Transactional
public Subscription activate(@Valid Subscription subscription, @Valid Payment payment) {
    Set<Payment> payments = subscription.getPayments();
    if (payments == null)
        payments = new HashSet<>();

    payments.add(payment);

    return subscriptionRepository.save(subscription);
}
```

**Classes:**

Subscription:

```
@Entity
public class Subscription {
...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "payment_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = true)}
    )
    @Getter @Setter
    private Set<Payment> payments;
}
```

Payment:

```
@Entity
public class Payment {
    @Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private PaymentType paymentType;

    @Past
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    public enum PaymentType {
        MONEY,
        PROMO_CODE,
        TRIAL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to inject the payments in the subcription , your repository and pojo seem just fine

```
if (payments == null) {
    payments = new HashSet<>();
    subscription.setPayments(payments);
 }
```

Comment: oh silly me... Thank you, I guess sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to detect something like that :D

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to mark your method with `@Transactional` annotation, cause the Spring Data `save` method **does not execute explicit save action**, it just selects a database row identifier and sets it to your entity.

1) Mark your method as @Transactional (best solution)
2) Inject EntityManager and create a transaction manually.

P.S.: JPA Persistence with Hibernate advises to initialize your collections in your model class (No lazy initialization). It reduces a lot of boilerplate checks and sometimes the realization shows Hibernate which Hibernate built-in collection to use (bags etc)

Comment: It actually is marked `@Transactional`, I just forgot to paste it. So you mean I can't call save on a repository and have to do it some other way?